# Probability of red cards

Tags: probability

A Person takes 26 cards at random from a 52-card deck, and He give those to and asks me to draw out 2 cards in a row without replacement . What is the probability that the both cards I draw will be the red cards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same as when you pick the two cards from the original 52 cards. Taking the 26 cards is irrelevant.

So the answer is $26 / 52 \cdot 25 / 51 = 25 / 102.$ Note that $26 / 52 = 1/2$ is the probability that the first card is red, and $25 / 51$  is the probability that the second card is red, given that the first was, as 25 of the remaining 51 cards are red.

Comment: Could you provide some intuition/justification as to why taking the 26 first doesn't affect the answer?

Comment: @Alex 1) Take the two top cards from the a shuffled deck. 2) Take the 26 top cards from a shuffled deck, and then take the top two from that half-deck. Same experiment. Here's another analogy: For each pair of cards from the original 52 card deck, are any of them more likely to be the final two you end up with, if you first pick 26 then 2 or just pick 2?

Comment: @Ned that makes sense, thanks!